# How can I format the output of clarity design datepicker with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, vmware-clarity

I am developing an angular application with clarity design.

There is a datepicker inside the form tag. The date value from there is 10.15.2021. but the format I need is 2021-10-15T17:56:30.728Z.

The clarity design official document says if you get [(clrDate)]="date" like this, it will output 2021-10-15T17:56:30.728Z, but I don't want to use ngmodel. I am using reactive form.

How can I format date information from formcontrol.
codes below

```
<form [formGroup]="logggForm" clrForm>
    <clr-input-container>
      <label class="clr-col-lg-4">Email:</label>
      <input class="clr-col-lg-8" clrInput formControlName="userEmail" placeholder="asd@asd.com" type="text"/>
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-date-container>
      <label class="clr-col-lg-4">Start date:</label>
      <input class="clr-col-lg-8" clrDate formControlName="from" type="date"/>
    </clr-date-container>
    <clr-date-container>
      <label class="clr-col-lg-4">To Date:</label>
      <input class="clr-col-lg-8" clrDate formControlName="to" type="date"/>
    </clr-date-container>
    <button (click)="click()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
  </form>
```

Ts code

```
logggForm= new FormGroup({
    userEmail: new FormControl(''),
    from: new FormControl(new Date()),
    to: new FormControl('')
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your question and I'm pleased you found an anwser yourself. You can write an answer to your own question and this can help others who come across the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **after another 30 min** **I found a simpler way to get the output I want without using DatePipe**

```
  let formatDate = this.logggForm.value.dateFrom.split('.');
  let formattedDatefrom = formatDate[2] + '-' + formatDate[1] + '-' + formatDate[0] + 'T00:00:00';
  data.from = formattedDatefrom;
```

first of all

```
this.logggForm.value.dateFrom = '15.10.2021'
```

then i split it '.' to array.

I was able to get the output I wanted by using the array.

Answer (score 0):

### 30 min later. I solved my question.

Add:

1-

```
providers: [DatePipe]
```

2-

```
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe)
```

3-

```
   let formattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.logggForm.value.from, 'yyyy-dd-MMT00:00:00');
```

I was able to get the output I wanted.